# Python - How to encrypt an integer to letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, encryption, mapping

I am writing a code where I could map from digits to letters as follows:

```
0 -> ‘Z’, 1->’X’, 2->’T’, 3->’J’, 4->’A’, 5->’W’, 6->’F’, 7->’S’, 8->’B’, 9->‘V’
```

For example, the integer `1234` is the string `“XTJA”`

```
1->’X’, 2->’T’, 3->’J’, and 4->’A’
```

However, whenever I am running the below code, it always shows an error message of

> 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'et(10)'

I do not really know what that means. **Also, is there a way to use a recursive function to get the same result?**

Greatly appreciated!

```
m=int(input())
sm=str(m)
e="ZXTJAWFSBV"

def et(x):
    o=''
    for i in sm:
        try:
            o += e[i-1]
        except:
            pass          
    return et(m)
```

Comment: I think you mean mapping/encoding? Encrypting is the process of securing a chunk of data with a key, to make it irreversible unless you have said key (or a decryption key, in the case of asymmetrical encryption). I don't think you mean you want to encrypt your text.

Answer (score 0):

> Use pertinent names for your variables

---

The problem is simplier:  for each digit of the input, take the letter in the key pointed by that index

```
def encrypt(w, key):
    result = ''
    for digit in w:
        try:
            result += key[int(digit)]
        except:
            pass
    return result


word = input("Please enter a word: ")
key = "ZXTJAWFSBV"

res = encrypt(word, key)
print(res)
```

---

Example

```
Please enter a word: 0123456789
ZXTJAWFSBV
```